# Stuck with JavaScript array looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, grouping

I have an array like this:-

```
[
    {"brand":"cadbury","category":"silk"},
    {"brand":"biba","category":"tops"},
    {"brand":"cadbury","category":"fruitnut"}
]
```

And I want to convert it to below format, tried many ways to do but not succedded:-

```
[
    {"brand":"cadbury","category":[{"name":"silk"},{"name":"fruitnut"}]},
    {"brand":"biba","category": [{"name":"tops"}] }
]
```

Basically after loop I want to combine all brands together.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: What you are trying to do is usually called "grouping". It is often implemented by utilities such as those in lodash called `_.groupBy`. Search for `grouping javascript array` and you will find lots of references.